# How to format a very long text on a TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

How to format my text in TextBox?

My text value is:

> 00010001008002020100010000530997000014820000148200010000012C00001482000014820000148200010000012C000014820000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000003F

And I want my output to be like this:

> 00010001-0080-02020100010000-53099700-00148200-00-14820001-0000-012C0000-14820000-1482000-0148-20001000-0012C000-0148-20000000-00000000-0000-00-000000000-00000000-0000-00000000-0000000-0000-00000000-00000000-00000000-0000-00000000-00-00000-000001010-00000000-000000000-0000-000000000-00000003-F

Comment: I suggest use jquery for format your text

Comment: i am using C#.net sir. for window forms

Comment: What's the pattern exactly? It seems so Irregular.

Comment: thats my pattern sir. i used string.format. but it is not applicable in that kind amount of text

Comment: how do you know where to put the hyphens?

Comment: Write your own custom formatter. [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1ksz8yb7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The you know the index at which to insert the hyphens.. try to use string.Insert() method, preferrably start from the last index, since if you start from the begining of the string, the length and hence indices will keep changing after every insert

Comment: @user3562783 You should explain the rule

Comment: thats the pattern sir. that's why im having a hard time to do it. it has no pattern.

Comment: If there's no pattern, then just put hyphens in random places.

Comment: So, how would the code know where to put the formatting?  If it's a a certain index, then you just simply have to write a custom method that places those hyphens at certain indexes in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format must be fixed. It should not be dynamic.

I am just providing a logic you could append the further detail in regex string.

```
string mystring = "000100010080"
string regex = @"(\w{4})(\w{4})(\w{4})";
string strValue = Regex.Replace(mystring, regex, @"$1-$2-$3");
```

OUTPUT:

```
0001-0001-0080
```

**EDITED:** Take a look at complete example

```
string[] patern = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XX-XXXXXXXX-
                   XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-
                   XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-
                   XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XX-
                   XXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-
                   X".Split('-');

string mystring = "00010001008002020100010000530997000014820000148200010000012C0
                   0001482000014820000148200010000012C00001482000000000000000000
                   0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                   0000000000000000000000000000001010000000000000000000000000000
                   00000000003F";

string regex = string.Empty;
string match = string.Empty;
for(int i=0; i<patern.Length;i++)
{
    regex += @"(\w{" + patern[i].Length + "})";
    match += "$" + (i + 1).ToString() + "-";
}
match = match.Substring(0, match.Length - 1);

txtMyTextBox.Text = Regex.Replace(mystring, regex, match);
```

Comment: sir? can i ask one more question? Regex is not appearing in my objects. is there anything that i should add for me to use this?

Comment: Have you imported a namespace `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` in your form?

Comment: this might be the answer that i am looking for :)

Comment: hi sir? i am wondering if can we direct save this to database?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a fixed pattern of inserting hyphens and the string length is same every time, then you could do something like this:

```
int[] indices = new int[] { 2, 5, 11 };
string yourLongString = "blahblahblah";

foreach( var index in indices.Reverse() )
{
    yourLongString = yourLongString.Insert( index - 1, "-" );
}
```

**OR**

Assuming you have no predefined pattern, you could insert hyphens anywhere and hence still you could use the same code above with the tweak to randomize the indices array, if needed.

Comment: int[] indices = new int[] { 2, 5, 11 };
 how pattern i can put here?

Comment: My pattern was to insert hyphen at 2, 5, 11 positions of my string "blahblahblah". Now figure it out for yourself.

Comment: ok. I'm asking sir if I can put any ammount of pattern on that code?

Comment: Give it a try and see what happens